# How to optimize extracting data from nested hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

## Background

I have a collection of nested hashes which present a set of parameters to define application behavior:

```rb
custom_demo_options: {
    verticals: {
        fashion: true,
        automotive: false,
        fsi: false
    },
    channels: {
        b2b: true,
        b2c: true
    }
}

website_data: {
    verticals: {
        fashion: {
            b2b: {
                code: 'luma_b2b',
                url: 'b2b.luma.com'
            },
            b2c: {
                code: 'base',
                url: 'luma.com'
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The choices made in the `custom_demo_options` hash relate to data stored in the `website_data` hash and serve to return values from it:

```rb
data = []
collection = {}
custom_demo_options[:verticlas].each do |vertical_name, vertical_choice|
    # Get each vertical selection
    if vertical_choice == true
        # Loop through the channels for each selected vertical
        custom_demo_options[:channels].each do |channel_name, channel_choice|
            # Get each channel selection for each vertical selection
            if channel_choice == true
                # Loop through the website data for each vertical/channel selection
                website_data[:verticals].each do |site_vertical, vertical_data|
                    # Look at the keys of the [:website_data][:verticals] hash
                    # If we have a vertical selection that matches a website_data vertical...
                    if site_vertical == vertical_name
                        # For each website_data vertical collection...
                        vertical_data.each do |vertical_channel, channel_value|
                            # If we have a matching channel in the collection...
                            if vertical_channel == channel_name 
                                # Add the channel's url and code to the collection hash
                                collection[:url] = channel_value[:url]
                                collection[:code] = channel_value[:code]
                                # Push the collection hash(es) onto the data array
                                data.push(collection)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data pushed to the data array is ultimately used to create the following nginx map definition:

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    luma.com base;
    b2b.luma.com luma_b2b;
}
```

As an example of the relationship between the hashes, if a user sets `custom_demo_options[:channels][:b2b] to`false`, the b2b code/url pair stored in the`website_data` hash would be removed from the nginx block:

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    luma.com base;
}
```

## Question

The above code works, but I know it's horribly inefficient.  I'm relatively new to ruby, but I think this is most likely a logical challenge rather than a language-specific one.

My question is, what is the proper way to connect these hashes rather than using loops as I've done?  I've done some reading on `hash.select` and it seems like this might be the best route, but I'd like to know: are there are other approaches I should consider that would optimize this operation?

## UPDATE

I've been able to implement the first suggestion (thanks again to the poster); however, I think the second solution will be a better approach. Everything works as described; however, my data structure has changed slightly, and although I understand what the solution is doing, I'm having trouble adapting accordingly.  Here's the new structure:

```rb
custom_demo_options = {
    verticals: {
        fashion: true,
        automotive: false,
        fsi: false
    },
    channels: {
        b2b: true,
        b2c: true
    },
    geos: [
        'us_en'
    ]
}
website_data = {
    verticals: {
        fashion: {
            us_en: {
                b2b: {
                    code: 'luma_b2b',
                    url: 'b2b.luma.com'
                },
                b2c: {
                    code: 'base',
                    url: 'luma.com'
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

So, I add another level to the hashes, `:geo`.

I've tried to adapt the second solution has follows:

```rb
class CustomOptionsMap
    attr_accessor :custom_options, :website_data

    def initialize(custom_options, website_data)
        @custom_options = custom_options
        @website_data = website_data[:verticals]
    end

    def data
        verticals = selected_verticals
        channels = selected_channels
        geos = selected_geos

        # I know this is the piece I'm not understanding.  How to map channels and geos accordingly.
        verticals.map{ |vertical| @website_data.fetch(vertical).slice(*channels) }
    end

    private
    def selected_geos
        @custom_options[:geos].select{|_,v| v } # I think this is correct, as it extracts the geo from the array and we don't have additional keys
    end
    def selected_verticals
        @custom_options[:verticals].select{|_,v| v }.keys
    end
    def selected_channels
        @custom_options[:channels].select{|_,v| v }.keys
    end
end

demo_configuration = CustomOptionsMap.new(custom_demo_options, website_data)
print demo_configuration.data
```

Any guidance on what I'm missing regarding the map statement would be very much appreciated.

Comment: While both answers were helpful in solving the problem I presented, I feel the OOP approach is a better solution for my specific need. It's also easier to read and understand in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Object Oriented** approach.

Using OOP might be more readable and consistent in this context, as Ruby is Object Oriented language. 
Introducing simple Ruby class and using `activesupport` module, which is extending Hash with some useful methods, same result can be achieved in the following way:

```
class WebsiteConifg
  attr_accessor :custom_options, :website_data

  def initialize(custom_options, website_data)
    @custom_options = custom_options
    @website_data   = website_data[:verticals]
  end

  def data
    verticals = selected_verticals
    channels = selected_channels

    verticals.map{ |vertical| @website_data.fetch(vertical).slice(*channels) }
  end

  private
  def selected_verticals
    @custom_options[:verticals].select{|_,v| v }.keys
  end

  def selected_channels
    @custom_options[:channels].select{|_,v| v }.keys
  end
```

Based on passed `custom_demo_options` we can select verticals and channels of only those keys, which values are set as `true`.

For your configuration will return

```
selected_verticals #  [:fashion]
selected_channels  #  [:b2b, :b2c]
```

`+data()`
Simple public interface is iterating through all selected `verticals` based on the passed options and return Array of hashes for the given channels by using `slice(keys)`.

`fetch(key)` 
return value for the given key it is an equivalent of h[:key]

```
h = {a: 2, b: 3}
h.fetch(:a)  # 2
h.fetch(:b)  # 3
```

`slice(key1, key2)` does require `activesupport`

returns hash which contains passed as an arguments, keys. Method is accepting multiple arguments, as in our example we are getting an Array of those keys, we can use `*` splat operator to comply with this interface.

```
h = {a: 2, b: 3}
h.slice(:a)         # {:a=>2}
h.slice(:a, :b)     # {:a=>2, :b=>3}
h.slice(*[:a, :b])  # {:a=>2, :b=>3}
```

**Usage**

```
  website_config = WebsiteConifg.new(custom_demo_options, website_data) 
  website_config.data   

  # returns
  # [{:b2b=>{:code=>"luma_b2b", :url=>"b2b.luma.com"}, :b2c=>{:code=>"base", :url=>"luma.com"}}]
```

**UPDATE**

Changed relevant parts:

```
def data
    verticals = selected_verticals
    channels = selected_channels
    geos = selected_geos

    verticals.map do |vertical|
      verticals_data = @website_data.fetch(vertical)

      # in case of multiple geolocations
      # collecting relevant entries of all of them
      geos_data = geos.map{|geo| verticals_data.fetch(geo) }

      # for each geo-location getting selected channels 
      geos_data.map {|geo_data| geo_data.slice(*channels)  }
    end.flatten
  end

  private 
  # as `website_data' hash is using symbols, we need to covert string->sym 
  def selected_geos
    @custom_options[:geos].map(&:to_sym)
  end

  def selected_verticals
    selected_for(:verticals).keys
  end

  def selected_channels
    selected_for(:channels).keys
  end

  def selected_for(key)
    @custom_options[key].select{|_,v| v }
  end
```

Easiest way to understand what kind of output(data) you have on each of the steps in the `each(map)` iterator, would be to place there debugger
like: pry, byebug.

Comment: I haven’t had a chance to dig into this yet (as it contains many concepts with which I am (as of yet) unfamiliar), but I just wanted to thank you for taking the time to answer and for this suggestion. The act of getting values based on selections IS something I need to do in multiple places, and I was beginning to recognize the need for and benefit of an OOP approach. I’ll respond back when I’ve had a chance to explore. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to respond.  I did some reading on fetch and select after modifying my original data structure slightly.  Would you be willing to expand on your answer in light of my attempts?  I think this is a beautiful solution and am almost clear, I think...

Comment: Sure thing, @SteveK, you can take a look at updated version. Code could be further simplified, towards one-liner  `geos_data = geos.map{|lang| verticals_data.fetch(lang).slice(*channels) }`. I left an extended version with comments as it should be easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Ah, I see! Digging into the tree of data makes sense with the multiple `map` statements now!  My logic was good, I just don't know these operations well enough yet, and the conversion to symbol also makes perfect sense.  Gosh, what a help this is.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `key = :foo` and `hash = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }` - you want to know the hash's value for that key.

The approach you're using here is essentially

```
result = nil
hsh.each { |k,v| result = v if k == :foo }
```

But why do that when you can simply say

```
result = hsh[:foo]
```

It seems like you understand how hashes can be iterable structures, and you can traverse them like arrays. But you're overdoing it, and forgetting that hashes are indexed structures. In terms of your code I would refactor it like so:

```
# fixed typo here: verticlas => verticals
custom_demo_options[:verticals].each do |vertical_name, vertical_choice|
  # == true is almost always unnecessary, just use a truthiness check
  next unless vertical_choice
  custom_demo_options[:channels].each do |channel_name, channel_choice|
    next unless channel_choice
    vertical_data = website_data[:verticals][site_vertical]
    channel_value = vertical_data[channel_name]
    # This must be initialized here:
    collection = {}
    collection[:url] = channel_value[:url]
    collection[:code] = channel_value[:code]
    data.push(collection)
  end
end
```

You can see that a lot of the nesting and complexity is removed. Note that I am initializing `collection` at the time it has attributes added to it. This is a little too much to go into here but I highly advise reading up on mutability in Ruby. You're current code will probably not do what you expect it to because you're pushing *the same `collection` hash into the array multiple times*.

At this point, you could refactor it into a more functional-programming style, with some chained methods, but I'd leave that exercise for you

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation and the refactor.  The only slight issue I see is website_data[:verticals][site_vertical] -- since you removed one of the each statements, site_vertical isn't set.  It woks with vertical_name instead. I'll definitely take you up on reading about mutability in ruby.  My code actually comes from a chef recipe and template. I ran into what I think are chef-specific quirks which force me to declare the data array as an empty array outside of the rest of the code first.  In any case, the next unless approach was new for me and is much-appreciated!